# Hyperledger fabric nodejs REST api error: stream removed

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have a blockchain network which uses a `hyperledger fabric` framework. I am trying to integrate a REST API to this network using this repo:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest

I set required config variables such as private key, admin credentials. But I am stuck at this point because I am getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed",
    "code": 2,
    "metadata": {
      "_internal_repr": {}
    },
    "details": "Stream removed",
    "stack": "Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed\n    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/nrl/bitirme/blockchainauth/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/fabric-rest/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/nrl/bitirme/blockchainauth/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/fabric-rest/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)\n    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/nrl/bitirme/blockchainauth/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/fabric-rest/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)\n    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/nrl/bitirme/blockchainauth/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/fabric-rest/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)\n    at callback (/home/nrl/bitirme/blockchainauth/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/fabric-rest/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fabric-sdk-rest repository is very old and isn't maintained anymore. The last version of fabric that it might actually work with is hyperledger fabric 1.0. I wouldn't recommend you continue to try to make it work.

Comment: do you have another rest api library that can work with this version of hyperledger fabric ?

Comment: balance transfer here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer shows a custom implementation of a rest api for this specific application for fabric 1.4. There isn't a generic rest api from hyperledger to access either deployed chaincode or perform operational actions such as install/instantiate/upgrade or channel management for example. There could be 3rd party implementations however.